# pandas: достать определенную строку из таблицы

Tags: python, pandas

Пытаюсь достать определенную строку из таблицы, но, при попытке ее вытащить, ничего не происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью питона вытащить строку "Итого" в excel,

```
Федя 1 2 3 4 5
Петя 5 4 3 2 1
Итого 6 6 6 6 6
```

при условии, что эта строка итого может быть где угодно?

Comment: Нормальный пример исходных данные приведите в вопросе. и ваш код заодно.

Comment: я попросил помочь с примером, чем вам не нравятся исходные данные , если мне нужен запрос чтобы достать определенную строку?

Comment: я не вижу индекса вашей таблицы и названия столбцов. то, что вы предоставили - не исходные данные. поэтому, не поленитесь. предоставьте воспроизводимые данные и ваш код, как того требуют правила сайта. Иначе вопрос будет закрыт.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
res = df.query("""column_name == 'Итого'""")
```

PS данный код не тестировался, т.к. вы не предоставили в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных. В примере данных в вопросе отсутствуют имена столбцов и также непонятно является ли первый столбец индексом или собственно столбцом.

---

PPS На будущее - приводите в вопросе небольшой воспроизводимый пример входных данных (**в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл**) и **то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе**. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)